# How to write a uint64 to a parquet file with logical type DECIMAL

Tags: c++, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

How do I write a `uint64_t` value with a logical type of `DECIMAL(30, 0)` and physical type of `FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY` to a parquet file?

I describe my attempt below:

Because `parquet::StreamWriter` requires any `FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY` columns to have a `LogicalType::None` type ([code](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/b3ce0fa7b682c891a33b4ac44711e949f9eff577/cpp/src/parquet/stream_writer.cc#L166)), we cannot use the `>>` operator defined in `StreamWriter`. Therefore, we create our own class `MyStreamWriter` which accepts a `uint64_t` value, converts it to a `FixedLenByteArray`, and writes it via `FixedLenByteArrayWriter`.

When I try writing `uint64_t val = 2` using this method, the value is written as `2658455991569831745807614120560689152` in the parquet file, which is clearly incorrect.

The binary representation of `2658455991569831745807614120560689152` is `10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` so my hypothesis is that the write logic puts the correct bits in the most significant positions, but somehow zero-pads the rest.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a more straightforward way of writing `uint64_t` as decimals?

```
#include "arrow/util/decimal.h"
#include "arrow/io/file.h"
#include "arrow/type.h"
#include "parquet/schema.h"
#include "parquet/stream_writer.h"


class MyStreamWriter : public parquet::StreamWriter {
    using parquet::StreamWriter::StreamWriter;

  public:
    MyStreamWriter& writeDecimal(uint64_t v) {
        arrow::Decimal128 decimal(arrow::BasicDecimal128(0, v));
        std::array<uint8_t, 16> decimalBytes = decimal.ToBytes();
        const uint8_t* decimalBytesPtr =
                reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(decimalBytes.data());
        parquet::FixedLenByteArray flba(decimalBytesPtr);
        Write<parquet::FixedLenByteArrayWriter>(flba);
        return *this;
    }
};   

// Define our schema.
parquet::schema::NodeVector fields;
int32_t precision = 30;
int32_t scale = 0;
fields.push_back(parquet::schema::PrimitiveNode::Make(
            "my_decimal_col", parquet::Repetition::REQUIRED,
            parquet::LogicalType::Decimal(precision, scale),
            parquet::Type::FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY,
            arrow::Decimal128Type(precision, scale).byte_width()));

auto schema = static_pointer_cast<parquet::schema::GroupNode>(
        parquet::schema::GroupNode::Make("schema", parquet::Repetition::REPEATED, fields));

// Open the writer.
const shared_ptr<arrow::io::OutputStream> os = arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open(_filepath).ValueOrDie())
writer = make_unique<MyStreamWriter>(
        parquet::ParquetFileWriter::Open(os, schema));

// Try writing an arbitrary value.
uint64_t val = 100;
writer->WriteDecimal(val);
```

Comment: why `#include <arrow/io/file.h>` but `#include "arrow/util/decimal.h"`? Do you understand the differences between `""` and `<>`?

Comment: That was a typo, please ignore.

Comment: The documentation for `BasicDecimal128.ToBytes()` says it is using native-endian byte-order. So depending on your system and the convention you use in your parquet file you may have to reverse the decimalBytes `std::array`